# Cannot turn into embed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

It can't turn into embed even though i tried to made `richembed`, `discord.messageembed` and now `messageembed`.

Here is the code I used:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "sayembed",
    aliases: ["bc", "broadcast"],
    description: "Says your input via the bot",
    usage: "<input>",
    run: (client, message, args) => {
        message.delete();

        if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
            return message.reply("You don't have the required permissions to use this command.").then(m => m.delete(5000));

        if (args.length < 0)
            return message.reply("Nothing to say? feels sad man").then(m => m.delete(5000));

        if (args[0].toLowerCase() === "sayembed") {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setDescription(args.slice(1).join(" "))
                .setColor("RANDOM")

            message.channel.send(embed);
        } else {
            message.channel.send(args.join(" "));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Also, try to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused as to how to create embeds.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on("message", async (msg) => {
   const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() //embeds are part of the `Discord` object defined above
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');
   
    //send embed
    message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
}
```

Be sure to check out the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/), I included your `on message` statement to make it slightly easier to understand also.

Using the code you provided:

```js
if (args[0].toLowerCase() === "sayembed") {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() //added 'Discord'
        .setDescription(args.slice(1).join(" "))
        .setColor("RANDOM")

    message.channel.send(embed);
}
```